# Getting Status of Community Group

Tags: ektron

I have created one community group in ektron workarea and set it's membership as 'Restricted'.
I need to access the status of Community Group membership ( whether it's open or restricted) via ektron api.

Comment: version of Ektron is 8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful to know what code you've tried, in case you're just off by a minor detail. However, this code will retrieve a Community Group and allow you to determine whether a group is open/restricted or hidden. (Hidden groups are always restricted.)

So a group can be Open, Restricted, or Restricted & Hidden.

```
var CommunityGroupCRUD = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Community.CommunityGroupManager();
var Group = CommunityGroupCRUD.GetItem(1);
if (Group.Enroll)
{
    context.Response.Write("Open");
}
else
{
    if (Group.Hidden)
    {
        context.Response.Write("Restricted & Hidden");
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Write("Restricted");
    }
}
```